# How to transform a string input into an existing list

Tags: python, list, input

I'm struggling to assign an input that's in a form of a string to an existing list.
Example:

```
p1 = [2, 3, 4]
p2 = [4, 5, 12]
p3 = [4, 91, 31]
whichList = "Which list do you want? "
TheList = 'p' + WhichList
```

Here if the input is 2, I expect to receive [4, 5, 12], instead I receive, p2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
p1 = [2, 3, 4]
p2 = [4, 5, 12]
p3 = [4, 91, 31]
x=input("which list do you need?")
if(x=='2'):
  print(p2)
elif(x=='1'):
  print(p1)
else:
  print(p3)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to store all the list in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

```
my_dict = {
    "p1": p1, 
    "p2": p2, 
    "p3": p3
}
```

Then, as you did, to access any `p` list, you can build a key and use it to access values on the dictionary:

```
listNumber = input("which list do you need?")
listKey= 'p' + listNumber
print(my_dict.get(listKey))
```

Also, as you noticed, to read user input, you need to use [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input). For more details on how reading user input from, you can have a look at this [tutorial](https://www.askpython.com/python/examples/python-user-input)